# How do I get just real time value from 'time' command?

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

I would like to make a script that outputs only the real time value from the time command so I can plot the results. For example `time command` outputs

```
real    1m0.001s
user    1m0.000s
sys  0m0.001s
```

I want to write a script that outputs

```
60.001
```

How do I get just real time value from 'time' command in seconds?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you're using the Bash builtin `time`, set the `TIMEFORMAT` variable to `%R`:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R
$ time sleep 1
1.022
```

Comment: Thanks! I like `%0lR` best (more readable) for slow-executing commands ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683434/custom-format-for-time-command/3686395#3686395 )

Comment: `unset TIMEFORMAT` to get back the original formating

Comment: rather than unset afterwords, I'd suggest `TIMEFORMAT=%R time sleep 1` per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942 but I just confirmed that it fails, presumably because time "forwards" somehow those declarations to the command, not to time.

Comment: @mellow-yellow: `time` isn't a command. It's referred to in the Bash manual as a reserved word. It is processed specially.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Is it possible somehow to apply `TIMEFORMAT=%R` for "reserved word" `time` _only_ for `time sleep 1` (i.e. w/o `unset TIMEFORMAT`)?

Comment: @pmor: One way would be to put it all on one line: `TIMEFORMAT=%R time sleep 1` . This sets the variable's value only in the environment of `time` and the executable being timed.

Answer (score 50):

`time` can take an optional `--format` or `-f` parameter, but you have to use the full path to the time command, `/usr/bin/time`

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" sleep 3

3.00
```

Without the path, it'll [use the `time` command of the shell](https://superuser.com/questions/112353/how-can-i-give-arguments-to-time-command-ubuntu) which just treats all arguments as the command, so you'll get an `-f: command not found`.

Comment: @frederik-b it doesn't on Ubuntu 19.04 `\time -f "%e" sleep 5` tells me that `bash: time: command not found`

Comment: This works with gnu time directly, but not shell's built in time commands, if you run `which -a time` you may see the shell's is preferred, this is why using the full path to the binary works in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

If you write `\time` you enforce not to use the bash built in time.
So with `\time -f '%e' command` you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use `/usr/bin/time` or take a look at the similar question
[Using time command in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683434/using-time-command-in-bash-script/).