# Ping test - display time taken when it fail to ping

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, pipeline

Newer to GitLab, by using simple ping test using bash script file I try to fetch the value of the test, success or failure and the duration of the ping.

pingtest.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$1
target=$2
testname=$3

ping -c $count $target >/dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]

then

echo $testname,Success,$(ping -c $count $target | sed '$!d;s|.*/\([0-9.]*\)/.*|\1|')

else

echo $testname,Failure,$(ping -c $count $target | sed '$!d;s|.*/\([0-9.]*\)/.*|\1|')

fi
```

.gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: centos

stages:
  - zero

job run_test_zero:
  stage: zero
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "report/*"
  script:
    - echo "TEST NAME|RESULT|DURATION" >> ./report/report.txt
    - chmod +x ./scripts/pingtest.sh
    - ./scripts/pingtest.sh 3 google.com pinggoolepass >> ./report/report.txt
    - ./scripts/pingtest.sh 3 google1.com pinggoolefail >> ./report/report.txt
```

report.txt file

```
TEST NAME|RESULT|DURATION
pinggoolepass,Success,6.066
pinggoolefail,Failure,
```

I'm unable to fetch the duration for failure ping test.

Please anyone suggest and guide me

Comment: `ping` on failure to resolve the host will just exit returning a non-zero code, it will not return the time taken for failure

Comment: Thanks @Inian. Is it possible to get the time taken in any other ways. Can any one suggest and guide me

Comment: Depends on what time you mean. If you want the time it takes for `ping` to exit, use [`time -f "%e" ping`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3795470/6770384). However, that value has no meaning and don't understand why you would want to print it. If you are talking about a timeout (not the case for google1.com) you might as well specify a timeout and use that value. By the way: Do you know that you run ping twice? First to check the exit code, then to extract the time.

Comment: Thanks @Socowi Can you suggest in single execution time and the exit code.

Comment: If my answer resolved your question please accept it. Accepting an answer closes this questions and rewards the author of the accepted answer. If your question was not resolved consider explaining why and adding more information to your question. If you are no longer interested in a solution you may as well delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

## Using `ping` Only Once

First of all, you don't have to execute `ping` twice. There are multiple ways to extract the exit status and max rrt time in one go. Here is an alternate version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
count="$1"
target="$2"
testname="$3"

if time=$(set -o pipefail;
          ping -c "$count" "$target" 2>&- | awk -F/ 'END {print $6}')
then
    result=Success
else
    result=Failure
fi
echo "$testname,$result,$time"
```

or you could replace the `if ... fi` part with

```
output="$(ping -c "$count" "$target" 2>&-)"
[ $? = 0 ] && result=Success || result=Failure
time="$(awk -F/ 'END {print $6}' <<< "$output")"
```

Both of these script are equivalent to your script and do not print a time in case `ping` fails.

## Measuring Time In Case of Failure

In order to *»fetch the duration«* you first have to specify what *»the duration«* is.

If you want the time it takes for `ping` to exit, use the `time` command or measure the time yourself with two calls to `date` or by using `$EPOCHESECONDS` in `bash` ≥ 5.0. However, that value has no meaning and I don't understand why you would want to print it.

If you are talking about a timeout (not the case for google1.com) you might as well specify a timeout yourself and use that value.