# Bridging between different programming languages

Tags: java, c++, python, c, thrift

This is more of a design question.

I was planning on writing some web-services which implement CPU intensive algorithms. The problem that I am trying to solve is - higher level languages such as python, perl or java make it easy to write web services. While lower level languages such as C, C++ make it possible to fine tune the performance of your code.

So I was looking at what I could do bridge two languages. Here's the options I came up with:

### Language specific bindings

Use something like perl-xs or python's ctypes/loadlibrary or java's JNI. The up-side is that I can write extensions which can execute in the same process. There is small overhead of converting between the native language types to C and back.

### Implement a separate daemon

Use something like thrift / avro and have a separate daemon that runs the C/C++ code. The upside is, it's loosely coupled from the higher level language. I can quickly replace the high level language. The downside being that the overhead of serializing and local unix domain sockets might be higher than executing the code in the same address space (offered by the previous option.)

What do you guys think?

Comment: I think that you've summarized your options pretty well. Beyond that it's a "how long is a piece of string"-type question.

Comment: I can't think why it would be hard to write a web service in C or C++ given a suitable toolkit/library. gSOAP for instance. The main issue is not the programming language but the talents of your programmers, and using two different languages obviously makes more demands on them.

Comment: Can these cpu-intensive algorithms be generalized?  If so, it's possible that there's already a Perl module that "does that", implemented with XS.

Answer (score 1):

If your C/C++ code already exists, your best bet is to publish it as a service, with an API matching what functionality you already have.  You can then write new services in the language of your choice, matching the API you need, and they can call the C/C++ services.

If your C/C++ code does not exist yet, and you are set to create the majority of code in a higher level language such as Java or C#, consider implementing the performance critical parts initially in that language as well.  Only after profiling shows a particular performance problem, and after you exhaust the most basic optimization techniques within the language, such as avoiding allocations inside the hottest loops, you should consider rewriting the bits that have been proven to consume the most cycles into another language using glue such as JNI.

In other words, do not optimize until you have numbers in hand.  There is also no fundamental reason why you couldn't squeeze out (almost) the same performance level from Java as you can from C++, with enough trying.  You have a real chance to end up with a simpler architecture than you expect.

Comment: Write with the language you are good at. Then think about performance. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

By your own reasoning, wouldn't it be better to implement the daemon with a higher level language? Which brings us back to step 1: how to provide access to your C code from that higher level language.

If you decide to write a daemon directly in C anyway the big down side to that is that you will have to maintain all the server code which is actually unrelated to the core functionality you're providing. That's one more thing to debug. And since it's a service it also needs to be kept secure and free from security holes.

But as you mentioned, writing an extension for a specific language in C means that you're essentially stuck with that language. Right?

Not necessarily. Let me introduce you to SWIG: http://www.swig.org/

With SWIG the job of writing the interface bridge between your C code and a target language is greatly simplified. In fact, where I work we even use it to interface with Java alone and will never use it's multi language support. It's a tool that auto-generates boilerplate code for you based on an interface file you provide.

Yes the interface file is yet another syntax to learn. And yes it does have its limitations. But it works remarkably well.

One big advantage of using SWIG is that your library is just a regular C/C++ library. Which tends to simplify and clarify code. It also means that you will also be able to directly use the library in a C/C++ project if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mongrel](http://mongrel2.org/) and just write the web service and highly performant code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

"The overhead of serializing and local UNIX domain sockets" is a non-issue.  Assuming the data exchanged between the daemon and the web service code will be about the same size (or smaller than) the data sent from the web service to the client over the network, the network will likely end up being your bottleneck anyway, and the overhead will be barely measurable.

Here's a script to test transferring 1GB over a UNIX socket (requires netcat-openbsd package and bash with large-number support, timing code borrowed from [Custom format for time command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683434/using-time-command-in-bash-script)):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f hello.sock
nc -l -U hello.sock | wc -c &
sleep 1
T="$(date +%s%N)"
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1048576 count=1024 | nc -U hello.sock
T="$(($(date +%s%N)-T))"
echo "$T nanoseconds / GB"
rm -f hello.sock
```

On my Intel Core i7 system, I get 1664042362 nanoseconds / GB.  Converting into gbit / s:

```
(1 GB / 1664042362 ns) * (1000000000 ns / s) * (8 gbit / 1 GB) ~ 4.8 gbit / s
```

On my system, this benchmark fully utilizes 2 cores (as determined by modifying the program to output several GB and looking at vmstat).  So if your Internet connection in gbit / s is K, and you have N cores, then the percent of CPU used by IPC when the network is fully loaded would be:

```
(K / 4.8) * (2 / N)
```

If you're using at least four cores, your bandwidth to the web service clients is 100mbps or slower, and the data transferred over IPC is about the same size or smaller than the data transferred from the web service to clients, this works out to 1% or less of your CPU being burned by IPC overhead.